# How to get Gridview's row data and pass to javascript through Json,JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I need to load my `GridView` control in `asp.net` using `Json` as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function ()
       {
           $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               url: "IndexCustomer.aspx/BindDatatable",
               data: "{}",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                   for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {


                       var input = '<input type="button" data-toggle="modal"  data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"  id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm" value="Edit" >';
                       var inputChek = '<input type="checkbox" id="chkRow">';
                       $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + inputChek + "</td><td class='hidden-field''>" + data.d[i].CustID + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Serial + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Customer + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].MobileNo + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].NIC + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].CustType + "</td><td>" + input + "</td></tr>");
                   }
               },
               error: function (result) {
                   alert("Error");
               }
           });
       });
</script>
```

where in first column i added `checkbox` and at last column of `gridview` i added `Edit Button` dynamically

**`Checkboxes` are only for deletion purpose not for edit functionality.**

and my `griview` is looking after loading data as

[image]

and when i click on `edit button` `bootstrap popup modal` appears where all the data need to populate in `textboxes`

without `Json` i did this by using `template field` in my `gridview` control and use `Eval Mehthod` as

```
    <ItemTemplate>
         <button  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" type="button" id=""   

 onclick="showDelModel('<%#Eval("CustID")%>','<%#Eval("FirstName")%>','<%#Eval("LastName")%>','<%#Eval("MobileNo")%>','<%#Eval("NIC")%>','<%#Eval("CustType")%>','<%#Eval("Gender")%>','<%#Eval("Phone")%>','<%#Eval("Fax")%>','<%#Eval("Email")%>','<%#Eval("Website")%>','<%#Eval("DefCust")%>','<%#Eval("Address")%>')"  class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm">Edit<i style="margin-left:10px" class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>   
                                                      </ItemTemplate>
```

and it worked great but now i need this functionality in that `input button` which was generated dynamically through `Json`..

I tried it as

```
var jsonStr = "'<%#Eval("CustID")%>','<%#Eval("FirstName")%>','<%#Eval("LastName")%>','<%#Eval("MobileNo")%>','<%#Eval("NIC")%>','<%#Eval("CustType")%>','<%#Eval("Gender")%>','<%#Eval("Phone")%>','<%#Eval("Fax")%>','<%#Eval("Email")%>','<%#Eval("Website")%>','<%#Eval("DefCust")%>','<%#Eval("Address")%>'";
                       var json = JSON.stringify(jsonStr);
                       json = JSON.parse(json)
                       var input = '<input type="button" data-toggle="modal"  data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"  id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm" value="Edit" onclick="showDelModel('+json+')">';
```

but it throws syntax error exception....

**NOTE:** where `showDelModel('+json+')` is `javascript` function which accept 
all parameters and assign them to relevant `text fields` in `Bootstrap pop modal`.

so i need your help to get out from this because i am new to `json`...

if you consider these details are not sufficient then please ask then i will provided you more

I am using `asp.net, Json, JQuery.`

Comment: JSON is a key value pair. While forming the jsonStr use it as key value pair. Ex, `"'CustID':'<%#Eval("CustID")%>','FirstName':'<%#Eval("FirstName")%>'"`

Comment: @AdityaSingh, I did according to you suggestion but it get empty while i inspect elements..... see this.....onclick="showDelModel('CustID':'','FirstName':'','LastName':'','MobileNo':'','NIC':'','CustType':'','Gender':'','Phone':'','Fax':'','Email':'','Website':'','DefCust':'','Address':'')"